# _id of mongo document subtracts one on jade

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, pug

I am finding with a rare problem between the node controller, the data base (mongodb), and the engine template jade. I show the piece of code and after I explain you.

## Code

The controller:

```
router.get('/get_my_buildings', function(req, res)
{
    if(req.session && req.session.user && (req.session.user.rol=="Admin" ||    req.session.user.rol=="superAdmin"))
        buildingDB.getBuilding({admin_id:req.session.user._id}, function(results)
        {
            if(results.error==1 || results.result.length==0) res.render('resource_not_found');
            else res.render('buildings/admin_buildings', {title:"WELLCOME", user:req.session.user, buildings: results.result});
        });
    else    res.render('users/loggin', {title:"LOGGING"});
});
```

---

Jade:

```
div(style="display: table;")
    for building in buildings
        div(style="display: table-row;" class="search_hit")
            div(style="display: table-cell;" class="not_search")
                span.glyphicon.glyphicon-map-marker
            div(style="display: table-cell;" class="inline") #{building.address[0].address}
            div(style="display: table-cell;" class="inline") #{building.address[0].city}
            div(style="display: table-cell;" class="inline") #{building.address[0].province}
            div(style="display: table-cell;" class="inline not_search input-group input-group-sm")
                a(type="button" href="/setup_building/#{building.address[0]._id}" class="btn btn-info inline")
                    span.glyphicon.glyphicon-tags.right-margin
                    |Setup
    else
        li I´m sorry, there is no building to show.
```

---

The trouble I´m finding is that here: **href="/setup_building/#{building.address[0]._id}"** allways subtracts one at the id than it should to write. 
For example, the id than should to be writen is: 545d384b9c33e76c07ba510d, but it writes: 545d384b9c33e76c07ba510e.
All the other dates are right. What am I doing wrong??

Thank you very much.
PS: I´m using express

Answer (score 0):

I know the problem now. This is the result when I make an "all buildings" request:

```
{
    "_id": "545d384b9c33e76c07ba510d",
    ...
    "address": [{
        ...
        "_id": "545d384b9c33e76c07ba510e"
    }]
}, {
    "_id": "545d5afc8e0295001bdf44e0",
    ...
    "address": [{
        ...
        "_id": "545d5afc8e0295001bdf44e1"
    }]
}
```

There are two very similar `_id` onto a `building`. The own `id` of the `building`, and the `_id` of the `address` object, which are very similar:

```
building: 545d384b9c33e76c07ba510d  
address:  545d384b9c33e76c07ba510e
```